# How to upgrade from magento 2 CE to Magento 2 EE?

Tags: magento2, migration

I hope you're doing well. I'm currently working on a Magento 2 CE based project, and I've run into a challenge. Specifically, for upgrading from magento 2 CE to Magento 2 EE.

Has anyone suggestion or have insights on how to approach it? Your expertise would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help!